# HTTPS GET request & read JSON reply

Tags: python, json, perl, https

As the title says, I need to send a HTTPS GET request, then read the JSON reply in plain text. I prefer python, but I can use perl as well.

EDIT: Allright, so now I can get the data from the page, but the reply data is SSL encrypted, how would I decrypt it?

Comment: `urllib2` and `json` should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:

```
import json
import urllib2
data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that for `urllib2` to handle an HTTPS request, the Python install needs to support SSL.

Answer (score 2):

For Perl:

```
use JSON; # We will use this to decode the result
use LWP::Simple; # We will use this to get the encoded data over HTTPS
use Data::Dumper; # We will use this to display the result

# Download the json data
my $encoded_json = get("https://domain.com/url");

# Decode the json data
my $result = decode_json($encoded_json);

# Show the result in readable form
print Dumper($result);
```